# setting and unsetting a session though an URL

Tags: php, session

Hi,

I need to create a session as soon as the visitor enters my page. Then by clicking on a link that takes to an URL like this `example.org/page?no_redirect=true` the session must be destroyed but the session should be created again if they click on a link to this URL `example.org/page?no_redirect=false.`

I did it like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['redirect'] = "false";
if($_GET['no_redirect'] == "true")
{
 $_SESSION['redirect']="true";
} elseif ($_GET['no_redirect'] == "false") {
 $_SESSION['redirect']="false";
}

if ($_SESSION['redirect']!=true) {
$redirect = <<<EOF
<script type='text/javascript'>DM_redirect("mobile/$page");</script>
EOF;
}
```

but its not working. What could it be?

Thank you.

Comment: Please check your if condition, might fail. Check without if condition in another page. Do unset the Session and debug before if condition.

Comment: put also else condition .

Comment: _"but its not working"_ - How do you know that? How  are you using that  session? Have you debugged it?

Comment: I tweaked it a little but it still wont work.

Comment: @AmitGupta is right. plus use this: `session_unset()` instead

Comment: The problem is that you're mixing strings and booleans. Both strings `"true"` and `"false"` are equal to the boolean `true`. Be consistent. If you're using strings when setting the session, use strings when comparing it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check `if ($_SESSION['redirect'] != true)` makes no sense, because you are comparing a non-empty string to a boolean. Non-empty strings always evaluate to `true`, so your check is really `if (true != true)`, which means the content inside the block will never be executed.

A more sensible approach would be to unset your session once its purpose has been served instead of setting it to `"true" / "false"`.

**Code:**

```
session_start();

# Check whether the session should be unset.
if ($_GET['no_redirect'] == "true") {
   unset($_SESSION['redirect']);
}

# Check whether the session should be set.
else if ($_GET['no_redirect'] == "false") {
   $_SESSION['redirect'] = "true";
}

# Check whether the session is set.
if (isset($_SESSION['redirect'])) {
   $redirect = <<<EOF
   <script type='text/javascript'>DM_redirect("mobile/$page");</script>
   EOF;
}
```

Comment: Its not working. After clicking the no_redirect=true link the variable $redirect still produces the value.

Comment: Then you have made a logical error in the code you've posted in your question. I edited my answer to correct that. Check it out @CainNukea.

Comment: I did check it but the session is not destroyed by clicking the no_redirect=true link

Comment: The code should be working fine. Are you sure you're putting it into the correct `PHP` file?

Comment: Yes, but its not working on my end. The $redirect value is not empty after I click on the link.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to include more information about your code and files in your question, if you want to get more specific help. The code provided in this answer should work unless something else in your code messes with it.

Comment: I have this code in my template. I can try by putting it in my index but I dont think it makes a difference.

Comment: I put it in my index page and it kinda works if the link is like this example.org/?no=redirect=true but not if its: example.org/somepage?no=redirect=true

Comment: That's how it works @CainNuke. Since you put it in your index file, it will work for your homepage. If you want it to work for `somepage` you have to put it in that page's file. Or better yet create a new `PHP` file and import that in every page you want using `include "custom_file.php"`.

Comment: My site structure is actually like this example.org/index.php?s=somepage but through a htaccess redirection they look like example.org/somepage so each page is rendered within the index.php file

Comment: Rendering within the `index.php` means that you include the page file in the index file. If so, put the code in the index file. If you use an `.htaccess` rewrite/redirection make sure that your rewrite uses the `QSA` flag along with any others you may have. Write `[QSA]` at the end of the line.

Comment: I will. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome @CainNuke. I'm glad I could help you 